# How to get media uris\files in app?

Tags: android

I would like to show all media files (photo and video) from my smartphone in my app.

At this moment I do this in this way:

```
    return new CursorLoader(this,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID },
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            sortOrder);
```

but this approach returns only photos.

What is the way to get uris for all videos on my device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Images` with `Videos` everywhere you see it in your code snippet above to get an equivalent code snippet for retrieving videos.

Comment: Thanks! Does it possible to obtain video and images in on request? Personally I would like to avoid using matrix cursor.

Comment: @Androiddev: Not that I am aware of.